# Convert string to javascript array with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I aplogize if this question has been asked before (this is my first question).
My string looks like this (after the whitespace has been removed:

```
"#home #blog description of page here ##article1 ##article2 #contact"
```

Which when parsed will return json object:

```
{
    home: {},
    blog: {
        description: "description of page here",
        pages: { 
            article1: {},
            article2: {}
        }
    },
    contact: {}
}
```

I would like to write a function that takes a string as a parameter and returns a json object. Any ideas?

Thanks in advace.

Comment: This won't be just a regex.

Comment: No, I am guessing it will have to be a recursive Javascript function that updates a regex or something.

Comment: It is incumbent on you to make effort to try to solve problem and when you have problems present code you are attempting to use. What have you tried?

Comment: Where should the "pages" and "description" property keys come from ?

Comment: @dystroy your answer looks good, why did you delete it?

Comment: @Christoph Because I don't understand if OP wants something generic or wants to hardcode some properties. My answer is incomplete anyway. I wanted to make something generic (which was fun). If OP wants something specific to those properties, then it's not interesting.

Comment: @dystroy I am glad I got your answer :). It is almost exactly what I need. I will try to modify it so that it can store the rest into the object as "description". Thanks so much.

Comment: And the pages and description properties are added if there is extra content before a new page (denoted by #{level}), or there are subpages.

Comment: @dystroy Nonetheless I find you answer +1able;) When modifying the regex to something like `/(#+)([^ ]+)([^#]+)/` this almost might be the answer to the question. And it still is pretty generic (depending on the definition of generic of course).

Comment: @Christoph I can't resist to the idea I might have a +1. Answer undeleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm not sure making this work is so obvious, here's a proposal :

```
var str = "#home #blog description of page here ##article1 ##article2 #contact";
var m, r = /(#+)([^# ]+)/g, o = {}, s = [o];
while (m = r.exec(str)) {
  var i = m[1].length - 1;
  s[i+1] = s[i][m[2]] = {};
}
```

The desired object is `o`.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/EPosuBed/1/)

Note that it doesn't do all because it's an attempt at a generic parsing solution and the input string you give doesn't provide everything (where are the "description" and "pages" keys ?). Please see it as a first step and as an encouragement to define a more rigorous generic format.

Comment: haha, there you go ^_^ Should be no problem for the OP to extend this solution to get the desired output.

Comment: I love the way you handled the array construction. Have never seen it done that way before. Took me half an hour to try and decode it haha!

Comment: @TristanMatthias Is everything clear now ?